# Vdc in ripple factor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, filter, rectifier, ripple

V_p(rect) is the rectified unfiltered peak voltage

V_r(pp) is the peak-to-peak voltage after filtering by a capacitor

Here is a picture:

[image]

V_r(pp) is given by the expression:

[image]

Which I have no problem with its derivation.

Now, as you can see with the first picture, the book shows that V_dc = V_p(rect) - 1/2  V_r(pp)

Why is that?

When he derives an expression for V_dc , this is what he does:

[image]

In short, why is V_dc the difference between the peak rectified unfiltered voltage and the peak-to-peak filtered voltage?

Here are also the circuit diagrams:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> In short, why is V_dc the difference between the peak rectified unfiltered voltage and the peak-to-peak filtered voltage?

That's not what $$  V_{dc} = V_{p(rect)} - \frac {1}{2} V_{r(pp)} $$

is saying. It is saying that "V<sub>dc</sub> is the peak rectified voltage and the peak *minus half the ripple*". This is clear from the graph.

In fact, and it is visible in the graph as drawn, this is an approximation. The area between the blue line and the average when above the blue line is greater than when below.

Comment: Understood, but why is Vdc like that in the graph at the first place? Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: It's just the average value of the voltage. It would be the same if it was a temperature, pressure or speed measurement.

Comment: Is that the same as the root mean square Vrms?

Comment: No. See [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-rectified-RMS-voltage-and-RMS-voltage-different-I-rectified-RMS-voltage-peak-voltage-2-and-RMS-voltage-peak-voltage-%E2%88%9A2) for some discussion on this. It will be close. Please unaccept my answer for a day or two to attract some more, possibly better, answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor charges to Vp every cycle. As an approximation, we can consider it to be relatively quickly charged right near the peak of the sine wave.

It then spends the rest of the cycle discharging into the load. So the peak voltage is Vp. The trough voltage is Vp-Vripple. The average voltage is approximately Vp-Vripple/2, since it's approximately a sawtooth.

The formula stated for the ripple assumes that the current is Vp/R so it is a bit conservative for large ripple. Generally these simplified formulas are accurate for small ripple relative to Vp (which is also typical of real designs).

Vdc is the average voltage and will be roughly equal to the RMS voltage for small ripple.

If the DC supply is feeding a linear regulator the average voltage will allow you to calculate the average power dissipation under normal conditions since the current drawn will be approximately constant.  So it's a useful number in many circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Vdc = Vac RMS x SQRT2/(1+1/2frc)  ac, rectifier, capacitor filter, load resistor.
f is ripple frequency after rectifier, c is Farads, r is OHMS.